# fancybox button helper does not show - no idea why

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Trying to use the fancybox plugin along with the button helper.  I am able to create a working gallery, but the button helper will not show.  I have verified all links and they are pointing to correct locations.  I have no idea why it is not showing and cannot see anything wrong.

I found some other posts that pointed out the button helper will not show unless you have a gallery, but I clearly do and it works... yet no button helper is showing.

**css:**

```
<link href="/assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/assets/plugins/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**js:**

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**test gallery links:**

```
<p><a class="fancybox-test" rel="fancybox-button" title="test one" href="/assets/img/gallery/image3.jpg">test</a></p>
<p><a class="fancybox-test" rel="fancybox-button" title="test two" href="/assets/img/gallery/image3.jpg">test</a></p>
```

**my initialization on document load:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-test").fancybox({
        prevEffect      : 'none',
        nextEffect      : 'none',
        closeBtn        : false,
        helpers     : {
            title   : { type : 'inside' },
            buttons : {}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: make sure you have the `fancybox_buttons.png` file under the same directory of `jquery.fancybox-buttons.css` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a z-index issue and needed to change :

```
#fancybox-buttons {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```